# Flink DataStream - how to start a source from an input element?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Say I have a Flink `SourceFunction<String>` called `RequestsSource`.

On each request coming in from that source, I would like to subscribe to an external data source (for the purposes of an example, it could start a separate thread and start producing data on that thread).

The output data could be joined on a single `DataStream`. For example

```
Input Requests: A, B
Data produced:
 A1
 B1
 A2
 A3
 B2
 ...
```

... and so on, with new elements being added to the DataStream forever.

How do I write a Flink Operator that can do this? Can I use e.g. `FlatMapFunction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds you are asking about an operator that can emit one or more boundless streams of data based on a connection to an external service, after receiving subscription events. The only clean way I can see to do this is to do all the work in the SourceFunction, or in a custom Operator.

I don't believe async i/o can emit an unbounded stream of results from a single input event. A ProcessFunction can do that, but only via its onTimer method.

Answer (score 2):

you'd typically want to use an [AsyncFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/asyncio.html), which (asynchronously) can take one input element, call some external service, and emit a collection of results.

See also [Apache Flink Training - Async IO](https://www.slideshare.net/dataArtisans/apache-flink-training-async-io).

-- Ken

Comment: As David Anderson points out below, the documentation of AsyncFunction (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/stream/operators/asyncio.html) indicates that the ResultFuture can only be called once, so it sounds like it cannot support an open-ended stream of results.

Comment: When you said "with new elements being added to the DataStream forever", I thought you were talking about incoming values, not the results of the external query - my mistake.

One work-around is to use an iteration to send the `A, B` values around continuously. Or (as David noted) you could use a `ProcessFunction` and timers, which we've done in the past. We've also successfully used a regular `FlatMapFunction` with a thread pool, but hanging onto the collector and re-using it feels risky and likely to break.